# Create a search filter by location but from a FlatList

Tags: react-native, search, react-native-flatlist

I want to create a search bar that will show from the nearest item. However, I don't want to use Google API and search from every business in Google. I have a specific set of business in my API (Hygraph). When the user select a category, I want to show the business from my API that fits that category, and I want it to show from nearest to furthest. I'm having a hard time finding how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

I've tried Google API but couldn't see how to use it only for my set of data instead of entire Google data.